# Using .netstandard2.0 NuGet with .NetFramework4.6.2

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I have a project in .NetStandard2.0 and this has to be used as a nuget in 2 projects, one in .NetCore2.2 and the other in .NetFramework4.6.2. Installing the nuget in .NetCore2.2 had no issues, but when I'm trying to install this package in the other project, I'm getting the following error -

> Could not install package 'packageName'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I also tried changing the target framework of this project from .NetFramework4.6.2 to .NetFramework4.7.2, but I'm getting the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: According to [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) you may have problems with 4.6 but it must work with 4.7.2. After changing target framework, have you rebuild properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had opened the Framework project in Visual Studio 2015 and this was causing the issue on trying to install the nuget package which was created in .NetStandard2.0. It was successfully installed when I tried it in Visual Studio 2017.